# Restrict access to Customer API Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, customer-registration, restriction

My website is getting 300+ spam users for a day, On checking it seems to be from   Customer API which Magento provides.

How can I stop this users, Is there any way that I can restrict the customer API.

Comment: You can have captcha or google captcha for genuine user validation.

Comment: I am sure that registration dint happen from signup, Its from API will captcha help for API hits.

Comment: Any one to help me on this.

Comment: I'm not sure but you can update "anonymous" to "self" in `vendor\magento\module-customer\etc\webapi.xml` or you should overwrite this file properly in your module.